# Access current file path in JetBrains Rider

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Is there any way to access file path to the current file in JetBrains Rider? I am looking for an environment variable or something similar that I can use to frame a URL, something that looks like `www.abc.com/$FILE_PATH$`

Comment: Based on your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59887583/783119) .. I assume you are trying to use External Tools functionality. In such case -- yes, Macro for such purpose is available. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Tools_Create_Edit_Copy_Tool_Dialog.html -- use "Insert Macro" to see available  and insert particular macro.

Comment: In my case, I want to open a url on browser and append the file path to it. Its not really an external tool

Comment: I want a functionality similar to "open in github", but I want to customize the url and not use github

Comment: I installed a plugin in Rider called 'CodeSearch'. It lets me open a url on the browser(hard coded like www.abc.com/). But I want to be able to let the tool know the file path to the current file to open the file I intend to.

Comment: You can use External Tools to execute external command (e.g. "open browser for this URL") and pass desired URL as a parameter.

Comment: I see..but the URL I have is not hard coded. It should append the path to the current file at the end of the url. How do I do that? Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: So .. assemble that URL as a parameter. Those available macro allow to get current file name, line and other stuff. Just check them.

Comment: Got it..thank you so much for all the help. I am all set

Comment: Please publish your solution as an answer then -- it will be useful for others in similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is curious, I did this.

Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools.

[image]

When I right click, I see "External tools" option. "I also mapped it to a keyboard shortcut.